# As in addon preferences add a button to install hotkeys?

Tags: python

As in addon preferences add a button to install hotkeys?

http://take.ms/15Voa

Comment: [This](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/info_tutorial_addon.html#keymap) shows how to setup a keymap.

Comment: https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?417586-Keymap-for-addons